# Is there anything to do in the onDestroyView() after a fragment is replaced?

Tags: android, memory

I have a fragment which contains a ViewPager that displays images onto the screen. When the user transitions to another screen through a button press and the current fragment is replaced with different fragment, do I have to do anything in the onDestroyView() method in order to release the ViewPager and the ImageViews contained in the previous fragment?

I'm just concerned that even though I do not see that fragment anymore, the ViewPager and ImageViews are still consuming memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your views are not garbage collected if you have instance variables referencing them. So if you are concerned about memory usage you should set them to null in onDestroyView.